# Jquery not getting full value from html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```js
$("#test").click(function() {
  alert($(".selected").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="selected" value="131cffb1-cff5-46c1-9bb1-865665c21ae8">weq Disponivel</li>
<button id="test">Button</button>
```

i want to be able to get the guid of the li by clicking that button, the problem is, i am unable to get it, can only get the first numbers like "131"

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this with a data-attribute.

```
<li class="selected" data-value="131cffb1-cff5-46c1-9bb1-865665c21ae8">
```

and then u can get the value with

```
var value = $('li').data(value);
```

```js
$('#test').on('click',function(){
              
       var test = $('li').data('value');
       alert(test);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="selected" data-value="131cffb1-cff5-46c1-9bb1-865665c21ae8">weq Disponivel</li>
<button id="test">Button</button>
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it -- the `value` property is only supported on form elements.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code:

```
alert($(".selected").attr('value'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using **.data()**

```
$("#test").click(function() {
   console.log($(".selected")[0].attributes[1].value);
   console.log($(".selected")[0].attributes[1].nodeValue);
   console.log($(".selected")[0].attributes[1].textContent);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/32hxtqfr/4/)

Comment: well, is not the text that i want. i want the value that has the guid inside it.

Answer (score 1):

you can't get the full value of list item cause it accepts only numbers and it is accepted only in ordered lists. What you need to do is to use custom html attribute like data with your profix so you don't have issues later with some jquery plugin.

This is example.

weq Disponivel

var value = $('li').data('prefixValue');

It is important to note that jquery will take camelcase 'prefixValue' and convert it to the right format with dashes and append 'data-' on the beginning. I hope this helps.